# List of all edge disjoint paths in a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

In a generic tree represented by the common node structure having parent and child pointers, how can one find a list of all paths that have no overlapping edges with each other and terminate with a leaf node.

For example, given a tree like this:

```
          1
      /   |   \               
     2    3    4
    / \   |   / \
   5   6  7  8   9
```

The desired output would be a list of paths as follows:

```
1    2    1    1    4
|    |    |    |    |
2    6    3    4    9
|         |    | 
5         7    8
```

Or in list form:

```
[[1, 2, 5], [2, 6], [1, 3, 7], [1, 4, 8], [4, 9]]
```

Obviously the path lists themselves and their order can vary based on the order of processing of tree branches. For example, the following is another possible solution if we process left branches first:

```
[[1, 4, 9], [4, 8], [1, 3, 7], [1, 2, 6], [2, 5]]
```

For the sake of this question, no specific order is required.

Comment: Are you looking for formal, working code, or just an algorithm?

Comment: Working code is better of course, I usually use Python rather than pseudo code as it's easier to test.

Comment: Hint: add a constraint so the solution is unique.

Comment: @BaselShishani Since you did not mention any language, I wrote an algorithm. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [recursive DFS algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) with some modifications.
You didn't say what language you use, so, I hope that C# is OK for you.

Let's define a class for our tree node:

```
public class Node
{
    public int Id;
    public bool UsedOnce = false;
    public bool Visited = false;
    public Node[] Children;
}
```

Take a look at `UsedOnce` variable - it can look pretty ambigious.
`UsedOnce` equals to `true` if this node has been used once in an output. Since we have a tree, it also means that **an edge from this node to its parent** has been used once in an output (in a tree, every node has only one parent edge which is the edge to its parent). Read this carefully to not become confused in future.

Here we have a simple, basic depth-first search algorithm implementation.
All the magic will be covered in an output method.

```
List<Node> currentPath = new List<Node>(); // list of visited nodes

public void DFS(Node node)
{
    if (node.Children.Length == 0) // if it is a leaf (no children) - output
    {
        OutputAndMarkAsUsedOnce(); // Here goes the magic...
        return;
    }

    foreach (var child in node.Children)
    {
        if (!child.Visited) // for every not visited children call DFS
        {
            child.Visited = true;
            currentPath.Add(child);
            DFS(child); 
            currentPath.Remove(child);
            child.Visited = false;
        }
    }
}
```

If `OutputAndMarkedAsUsedOnce` just outputed a `currentPath` contents, then we would have a plain DFS output like this:

```
1 2 5
1 2 6
1 3 7
1 4 8
1 4 9
```

Now, we need to use our `UsedOnce`. Let's **find the last used-once-node (which has already been in an output) in current path and output all the path from this node inclusively**. It is guaranteed that such node exists because, at least the last node in a path has never been met before and couldn't be marked as used once.

For instance, if the current path is "1 2 3 4 5" and 1, 2, 3 are marked as used once - then output "3 4 5".

In your example:

1. We are at "1 2 5". All of them are unused, output "1 2 5" and mark 1, 2, 5 as used once
2. Now, we are at "1 2 6". 1, 2 are used - 2 is the last one. Output from 2 inclusively, "2 6", mark 2 and 6 as used.
3. Now we are at "1 3 7", 1 is used, the only and the last. Output from 1 inclusively, "1 3 7". Mark 1, 3, 7 as used.
4. Now we are at "1 4 8". 1 is used, the only and the last. Output "1 4 8".
5. Now we are at "1 4 9". 1, 4 are used. Output from 4 - "4 9".

It works because in a tree "used node" means "used (the only parent) edge between it and its parent". So, we actually mark used edges and do not output them again.

For example, when we mark 2, 5 as used - it means that we mark edges 1-2 and 2-5. Then, when we go for "1 2 6" - we don't output edges "1-2" because it is used, but output "2-6".
Marking root node (node 1) as used once doesn't affect the output because its value is never checked. It has a physical explanation - root node has no parent edge.

Sorry for a poor explanation. It is pretty difficult to explain an algorithm on trees without drawing :) Feel free to ask any questions concerning algorithms or C#.

Here is the working [IDEOne demo](http://ideone.com/JbCNNp).

*P.S.* This code is, probably, not a good and *proper* C# code (avoided auto-properties, avoided LINQ) in order to make it understandable to other coders.

Of course, this algorithm is not perfect - we can remove `currentPath` because in a tree the path is easily recoverable; we can improve output; we can encapsulate this algorithm in a class. I just have tried to show the common solution.

Comment: He really should have listed a language for implementation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah. By the time the OP has mentionted Python as a desirable language in comments, I almost have completed the C# code. Anyway, I do not know Python :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a tree. The other solutions probably work but are unnecessarily complicated. Represent a tree structure in Python.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, label, children):
        self.label = label
        self.children = children
```

Then the tree

```
  1
 / \
2   3
   / \
  4   5
```

is `Node(1, [Node(2, []), Node(3, [Node(4, []), Node(5, [])])])`. Make a recursive procedure as follows. We guarantee that the root appears in the first path.

```
def disjointpaths(node):
    if node.children:
        paths = []
        for child in node.children:
            childpaths = disjointpaths(child)
            childpaths[0].insert(0, node.label)
            paths.extend(childpaths)
        return paths
    else:
        return [[node.label]]
```

This can be optimized (first target: stop inserting at the front of a list).

Answer (score 1):

For all vertices, if the vertice is leaf (has no child pointers), go through the parent chain until you find a marked vertice or vertice with no parent. Mark all visited vertices. Collect the vertices to the intermediate list, then reverse it and add to the result.

If you cannot add a mark to the vertice object itself, you may implement the marking as a separate set of visited vertices and consider all the vertices added to the set as marked.

Answer (score 1):

This can be very easily accomplished using **DFS**.

We call the DFS from root.

```
DFS(root,list)
```

where the list initially contains

```
list = {root}
```

Now the algorithm is as follows:

```
DFS(ptr,list)
{
 if(ptr is a leaf)
  print the list and return
 else
 {
  for ith children of ptr do
  {
   if(ptr is root)
   {
    add the child to list
    DFS(ith child of ptr,list)
    remove the added child
   }
   else if(i equals 1 that is first child)
   {
    add the child to list
    DFS(ith child of ptr,list)
   }
   else
   {
    initialize a new empty list list2
    add ith child and the ptr node to list2
    DFS(ith child of ptr,list2)
   }
  }
 }
}
```